# Inserting separate HTML file into lots of HTML files using jQuery / javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I need to create a navigation menu that can be edited separately and inserted into many html pages. Is there a way to do this using javascript / jQuery or does one have to use php? How can this be achieved?

Comment: Good, your requirement is clear enough but so far what did you try? BTW yes it's possible to include a reusable _control_ but solution varies a lot according to what you're using server side (well even a plain HTML page would work if _injected_ through AJAX request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with ajax, but It's easier, quicker and cleaner to do it in php.

with jquery:

```
$( "#navigation-container" ).load( "navigation.html" );
```

with php:

```
<? php include 'navigation.php'; ?>
```

To make php work you'll need a web server (such as XAMPP, MAMP, or similar)